# Float one navbar item right Bootstrap4 and keep centered links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-float, navbar

I'm trying to float the "login with discord" text and image to the right while the other 2 navbar links stay in the center. Whenever I tried to float it right the centered content/nav items got pushed over to the left about the width of the "login with discord" button. I'm trying to float it right without the center content moving. Here's my code.

```
<body class="text-center">
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
  <header class="masthead mb-auto mr-auto ml-auto">
    <div class="inner">
      <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="features.html">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="../img/discordnav.png"></img> Login With Discord</a>
      </nav>

    </div>

  </header>
```

Site/preview link - https://wojakbot-64140.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: You want to put it at the right end of your header or whole page?

Comment: Just to the top right separate from the other nav items while being on the same line as them.

Comment: Can you clean up the HTML and post all of the relevant navbar code? The preview link is different.

Answer (score 0):

just update below css and you're done, as you need to make that last child position absolute and header position relative, if you want further right then remove max-width or set it unset for ".cover-container".

```
a.nav-link:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.masthead {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please comment if this don't work for you, I've tested it on your live site as well...

Comment: I've added that CSS, nothing seemed to move. I couldn't find a.nav-link:last-child { in any of the CSS files I have imported to my index.html. So I wasn't sure if you just meant to add the code instead of edit.

Comment: Add above css if you have not added any css for those, it will work.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
Do you want to be like this?

[image]
code here

Comment: I added the code and it only seemed to move a little bit. https://i.imgur.com/4C9gg9s.png

Comment: It seems like it's stuck into this container, but I'm not sure how to adjust that. https://i.imgur.com/T0d8dmv.png

Comment: Yea, exactly like that.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Is there a way from stopping it from displaying over the other menu items when you resize the page?

Comment: why u not using responsive navigator bar? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav.

Comment: I just used the default navbar for the "cover" template from Bootstrap. Everything else is responsive besides that one navbar item we moved to the right.

Comment: can you draw it? because I do not English very well.

Comment: draw your idea.

Comment: mobile screen view, u remove class position absolute.